# SSRS 2008 tablix results missing values

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a report that takes an order number as a parameter and shows a tablix with each part number on a row along with the part description, number ordered, number shipped, number remaining to ship, and number on backorder.

SSMS shows the query returns the same number of rows as the tablix shows. However, the tablix has blanks in several places. I have no filters, no visibility settings, and no special conditions. I have zeros set to display as '-'.

The blanks occur below identical values in two columns: Number Shipped and Number Remaining. That is, a value is not shown (only in these two columns) if it is the same as the value above it, like this:

```
Item Desc #Ordered #Shipped #Remaining #Backorder
1H   abc         4        4          -          -
2R   def         1        -          1          0
5L   ghi         6                   6          3
7P   jkl         6        6          -          -
9Q   mno         6                              -
```

There should be a - (for zero) for 5L under #Shipped. 9Q should have a 6 under #Shipped and a - under #Remaining, like this:

```
Item Desc #Ordered #Shipped #Remaining #Backorder
1H   abc         4        4          -          -
2R   def         1        -          1          0
5L   ghi         6        -          6          3
7P   jkl         6        6          -          -
9Q   mno         6        6          -          -
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

In the query, try isnull(#Shipped,'-') to catch the rest of the blanks.
If that doesn't work, use the TextBox Expression:

```
=switch(len(#Shipped)>0,#Shipped,True,"-")
```

This will replace the blank values with a dash to match the others.

Comment: I created two new columns, copied the two columns into the new columns, and deleted the columns that had this problem. Problem solved! The fix was simple. However, I still don't know the cause.